# Why RecyclerView loses focus on click?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview in fragment and in item click I add another fragment that show details for item. But when I returned back in first fragment, clicked item lose focus and cannot triggered click.

```
DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
    Bundle b = detailsFragment.getArguments();
    if (b == null) {
        b = new Bundle();
    }
    b.putString(Constants.ID, id);
    detailsFragment.setArguments(b);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .hide(this)
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, detailsFragment, DetailsFragment.class.getSimpleName())
            .addToBackStack(DetailsFragment.class.getSimpleName())
            .commit();
```

Comment: You need to POST more code. What code you done in your OnBackPressed method?

Comment: Agreed @divyesh. What does your listener look like? What are you doing when you resume the last fragment?

Comment: in onbackpress I call getFragmentManager().popBackStack();